# Undefined colour profile

Tags: javascript, null, photoshop-script

I'm trying to remove colour profiles from a document. As far as I am aware, the colorProfileName should be either a string or null (if it's not assigned). However, if it's the latter I can't assign it to a variable (line 3).

Without the try/catch is there a way around this?

```
try {
    var cp = app.activeDocument.colorProfileName;
} catch(eek) {
    alert("no colour profile associated with image");
    cp = null;
}

if (cp != null) {
    cp = assignNoColourProfile(cp);
    if (cp == null) {
        alert("colour profile now removed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only have access to Photoshop CS5 and the description of colorProfileName says:

> Valid only when colorProfileType = ColorProfile.CUSTOM or WORKING.

So maybe it's a good idea to check that before:

```
var cp = null;
if (app.activeDocument.colorProfileType != ColorProfile.NONE)
    cp = app.activeDocument.colorProfileName;
```

Michael / Hamburg